# Каким образом в Майнкрафт можно включить RTX если майнкрафт на OpenGL

Tags: minecraft, render

Майнкрафт написан на OpenGL использующий метод растеризации. Но как тогда в нём можно включить RTX, если это совершенно другая система рендеринга

Comment: Minecraft Bedrock написан на DirectX

Comment: Ну так а я про java

Comment: Ну так в java и нету никакого RTX